# ¿Cómo hacer un mega menú ajustable al contenido en WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

En WordPress, estoy usando un Mega Menú elaborado con el plugin Max Mega Menú, el cual se ve muy bien en 4 o 6 columnas, éste tiene por default un ancho definido (el cual puedo modificar en el propio plugin), sin embargo, requiero que al usar dos o una columna, se ajuste al ancho del contenido, ya que ahora se muestra con espacio blanco entre columnas.

Para que se ilustre mejor el ejemplo, requiero copiar el estilo de menú de este sitio: https://saddlecreekortho.com/ y el sitio en el que estoy usando el Max Mega Menu es http://nischli.firefish.com.mx

Supongo que puedo usar CSS, he intentado con este código (que se incluye en la documentación) pero no funciona:

```
@include desktop {
#{$wrap} #{$menu} {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    > li.mega-menu-item {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 1;
        flex: 1 1;

        /** Do not grow menu items with ".mega-no-flex" class **/
        &.mega-no-flex {
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            -webkit-flex: 0 0;
            -ms-flex: 0 0;
            flex: 0 0;
        }

        /** Center align text within menu item **/
        > a.mega-menu-link {
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy usando BeTheme.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar cuál es la problematica que tienes, es decir, que hace el otro que el tuyo no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola que tal veo que los espacios blancos los estan modificando estas reglas css en tu style.css

`#mega-menu-wrap-main-menu #mega-menu-main-menu li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row .mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width: 100%;
}`

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, quedó resuelto.